# Excel macro to traverse back and identify the source of a target field

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone please help me with a VBA Excel macro to traverse back to find the source

these are all in the excel sheet

```
type   sub type    source  target
v4      v41        z2      z1
v4      v41        y4      y3
v3      v32        y3      y2
v3      v32        z1      b3
v3      v31        b4      b3
v2      v21        y2      y2
v2      v21        x3      x2
v2      v21        b3      b2
v2      v21        a3      a2
v1      v11        y2      y1
v1      v11        x2      x1
v1      v11        b2      b1
v1      v11        a2      a1
```

In the above example for each variable type in (v1), I need to traverse and identify the source variable

a1 source will be a3  and route will be a1 to a2, a2 to a3
but for b1 it will have two sources b4 and z2 and the route will be b1 to b2, b2 to b3 and b3 to (b4 and z1), and z1 to z2, and for x1 it will be x3  and the route will be x1 to x2, x2 to x3 and for y1 it will be y5 and the route will be y1 to y2, y2 to y3 to y4, y4 to y5.

the code i tried..

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim prime_var   As String
Dim curr_var    As String
Dim prev_var    As String
Dim source_var  As String
row_count = 1
While Sheet1.Range("A" & row_count) <> ""
    row_count = row_count + 1
Wend
    row_count = row_count - 1
While row_count > 1
    prime_var = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_count) + Sheet1.Range("B" & row_count)
    curr_var = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_count - 1) + Sheet1.Range("B" & row_count - 1)
    new_count = row_count
    prev_var = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_count) + Sheet1.Range("B" & row_count)
    source_var = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_count)
    
    While new_count > 1
        While curr_var = prev_var And new_count > 1
            curr_var = Sheet1.Range("A" & new_count) + Sheet1.Range("B" & new_count)
            new_count = new_count - 1
        Wend
        If source_var = Sheet1.Range("d" & new_count) Then
            source_var = Sheet1.Range("c" & new_count)
        End If
            prev_var = Sheet1.Range("A" & new_count) + Sheet1.Range("B" & new_count)
            curr_varCode
        new_count = new_count - 1
        prev_var = Sheet1.Range("A" & new_count) + Sheet1.Range("B" & new_count)
    Wend
    row_count = row_count - 1
Wend
```

End Sub

The problem is I was not able to identify a solution for two sources (b1 it will have two sources b4 and z2)

Comment: Where is the result shown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses recursion with a dictionary holding a collection of sources for each target and an array holding the steps from target to source.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim dict As Object, key, rngOut As Range
Dim steps() As String, iStep As Integer

Sub macro1()
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim sSrc As String, sDest As String
    Dim v As New Collection

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' input
    Set ws = Sheet1
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = iLastRow To 2 Step -1
        sSrc = Trim(ws.Cells(r, "C"))
        sDest = Trim(ws.Cells(r, "D"))

        If Not dict.exists(sDest) Then
            dict.Add sDest, New Collection
        End If
        dict(sDest).Add sSrc

        ' v1s
        If ws.Cells(r, "A") = "v1" Then v.Add sDest
    Next

    ' process and output
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear
    Set rngOut = Sheet2.Range("A1")
    ReDim steps(1 To 10)
    For Each key In v
        ' first step
        iStep = 1
        steps(1) = key
        Call traverse
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

Sub traverse()
    
    Dim dest As String, n As Integer
    ' expand array if needed
    If iStep > UBound(steps) Then
        ReDim Preserve steps(1 To iStep + 10)
    End If
    steps(iStep) = key
     
    If dict.exists(key) Then
        ' next steps
        While dict(key).Count > 0
            dest = dict(key).Item(1)
            dict(key).Remove 1
            ' traverse forward
            key = dest
            iStep = iStep + 1
            Call traverse
        Wend
    Else
        ' end of the line, output result
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(1)
        rngOut = steps(1)
        For n = 1 To iStep
            rngOut.Offset(0, n - 1) = steps(n)
        Next
        ' traverse back
        iStep = iStep - 1
        key = steps(iStep)
    End If   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code (assuming you have your data in columns A to D of the Sheet 1):

```
Sub TravBack()
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("G2") = "=D2&"".""&COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2)"
        .Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("G2:G" & lrow)
        
        For i = 2 To lrow
            If .Range("A" & i) = "v1" Then
                .Range("E" & i) = .Range("C" & i)
                Do
                    If Application.CountIf(.Range("D:D"), .Range("E" & i)) > 1 Then
                        .Range("F" & i) = .Range("E" & i) & ".2"
                        Do
                            .Range("F" & i) = .Range("C" & Application.Match(.Range("F" & i), .Range("G:G"), 0))
                            If .Range("C" & Application.Match(.Range("E" & i) & ".2", .Range("G:G"), 0)) = .Range("F" & i) Then Exit Do
                        Loop While IsError(Application.Match(.Range("F" & i), .Range("D:D"), 0)) = False
                    End If
                    .Range("E" & i) = .Range("C" & Application.Match(.Range("E" & i), .Range("D:D"), 0))
                Loop While IsError(Application.Match(.Range("E" & i), .Range("D:D"), 0)) = False
            End If
        Next i
        .Columns("G:G").Delete
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: it worked.. thank you, but if the value is the same it gives an error type mismatch..  I have updated the input.

Comment: Please check y series, y1 to y2, y2 to y2 again, y2 to y3, and y3 to y4

Comment: @MageshJ I updated the answer, try it now.